# is it possible to stop the calico Installation

Tags: kubernetes

Now I want to change the calico config in kubernetes (`v1.28.3`) cluster, everytime I change the config, it will be rollback by the Installation. is it possible to stop the Installation? this is the Installation look like(every resouce is controlled by this Installation):

```
apiVersion: operator.tigera.io/v1
kind: Installation
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2023-10-04T05:35:14Z'
  finalizers:
    - tigera.io/operator-cleanup
  generation: 4
  labels:
    k8slens-edit-resource-version: v1
  name: default
spec:
  paused: true
  calicoNetwork:
    bgp: Enabled
    hostPorts: Enabled
    ipPools:
      - blockSize: 26
        cidr: 10.96.0.0/12
        disableBGPExport: false
        encapsulation: VXLANCrossSubnet
        natOutgoing: Enabled
        nodeSelector: all()
    linuxDataplane: Iptables
    multiInterfaceMode: None
    nodeAddressAutodetectionV4:
      firstFound: true
  cni:
    ipam:
      type: Calico
    type: Calico
  controlPlaneReplicas: 1
  flexVolumePath: /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/
  kubeletVolumePluginPath: /var/lib/kubelet
  logging:
    cni:
      logFileMaxAgeDays: 30
      logFileMaxCount: 10
      logFileMaxSize: 100Mi
      logSeverity: Info
  nodeUpdateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  nonPrivileged: Disabled
  variant: Calico
```

I have tried to add configuration `paused: true` seems could not work. it will always rollback the calico configuration.